# Error en codigo de cv2 con python - Camara en vivo

Tags: python, python-3.x, cv2

```
import cv2

captura = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while (captura.isOpened()):
    ret,imagen = captura.read()
    if ret == True:
        cv2.imshow("Video", imagen)
        if cv2.waitkey(1) & 0xFF == ord("s"):
            break

captura.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Estoy empezando en esto del cv2 con python, y este codigo como pueden ver trata de utilizar la camara para hacer un video en vivo, pero cada vez que lo cargo me da error --> `[ WARN:0] global C:\users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-2y91i_7w\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (677) CvCapture_MSMF::initStream failed to set mediaType (stream 0, (640x480 @ 30) MFVideoFormat_RGB24 (codec no found)`

No se porque se causa este error pero si alguien me puedo ayudar se lo agradeceria muchisimo.

Comment: buena mi perro , intenta con esto , captura = cv2.VideoCapture(0,cv2.CAP_DSHOW)

Comment: Ya solucione el error perro, pero ahora me da un nuevo error en la linea 9 if cv2.waitkey(1) & 0xFF == ord("s"): de tipo AttributeError: module "cv2.cv2" has no attribute "waitkey"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ampliando el comentario de @altoqueperro si quieres grabar desde un fichero, necesitas cambiar el backend que lo hace, ya que no sirve el de OpenCV por defecto.

**El backend es el encargado de procesar el video**, el que funciona tanto para ficheros como para CAM es: `cv2.CAP_DSHOW` (Direct Show).

Por otro lado el otro error que te indica: `AttributeError: module "cv2.cv2" has no attribute "waitkey"` te está diciendo que **dicha función no existe en el paquete OpenCV.** La *"k"* es en mayuscula.

El código con ambas modificaciones quedaría así:

```
import cv2

captura = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)

while (captura.isOpened()):
    ret,imagen = captura.read()
    if ret == True:
        cv2.imshow("Video", imagen)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("s"):
            break

captura.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, me a funcionado de maravilla de verdad se los agradezco de ante mano

Comment: De nada, me alegro siempre de poder ayudar! :) . Probablemente no lo sepas, pero la mejor forma de dar las gracias en StackOverflow es marcando la respuesta como "respuesta correcta" y ¿por qué no?  Votar positiviamente la respuesta, esto además de ser una forma de dar las gracias a las personas que te ayudan, también sirve para posicionar la pregunta y que perdure en el tiempo, así podrá servirle a personas con el mismo problema que tu en el futuro!

Comment: Ya lo hice compañero, muchas gracias